# Reading files line by line in by using for loop bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop

Say for example I have a file called "tests",it contains

```
a
b
c
d
```

I'm trying to read this file line by line and it should output

```
a
b
c
d
```

I create a bash script called "read" and try to read this file by using for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ${1}; do //for the ith line of the first argument, do...
   echo $i  // prints ith line
done
```

I execute it

```
./read tests
```

but it gives me

```
tests
```

Does anyone know what happened? Why does it print "tests" instead of the content of the "tests"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/608639)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < "$1"
```

This solution can handle files with special characters in the file name (like spaces or carriage returns) unlike other responses.

Comment: For complete non-destructiveness, do `while IFS= read -r line` -- without "IFS=" you will lose leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: It is also possible to execute this as a pipeline, as e.g.: `ls -1 | while IFS= read -r line; do ... done`.  I also found that a bit easier to follow the sequence.

Answer (score 11):

You need something like this rather:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line || [[ $line ]]; do
  echo $line
done < ${1}
```

what you've written after expansion will become:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in tests; do
   echo $i
done
```

if you still want `for` loop, do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat ${1}); do
   echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just wondering, is it impossible to do it by using for loop?

Comment: @OKC pretty much.  @bobah the last line will get skipped if the file doesn't have a trailing newline ... `read line || [ "$line" ];` fixes that

Comment: @OKC, Michael's answer is close to what you were trying to do, but I would not recommend it.  It reads the whole file at once and does the equivalent of `set -- $(cat $somefile); while ([ "$1" ]) do stuff;shift;done` note that here $@ would get up to N variables (one for each occurence of a character from $IFS in the input file) ... and could use a LOT of memory for larger files

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `cat $1`
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: That prints "cat $1" :(

Comment: -1, this prints each *word* in the file on a separate line. While it's OK for this particular example, don't use it in the general case

Comment: @OKC, those are *backticks* not single quotes.

Comment: if line has empty spaces, each part is consider a new line